# What exactly does the wcf publishing wizard produce?

Tags: biztalk

I'm a bit confused on what the biztalk wcf publishing wizard produces?

So for example,  I have a simple biztalk project that takes a Input xml file,  maps it,  and outputs to another folder.

Can i use the wcf publishing wizard to create a webservice to pass in and out an xml to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. WCF Publishing wizard is for this purpose. You can either expose your schema as a service or your Orchestration. It has few options to choose e.g. whether you want to use BasicHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding or custom. You should have a local IIS configured for this. It will also create a receive location in BizTalk to receive the message from IIS service and return the response.

More details about it can be found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226547.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, yes, you would 'publish' the schemas.

To note, there is no difference in the output of either option.  Publishing an Orchestration merely reads some metadata from the compiled Assembly.  If you set the same values when publishing 'Schema', the output metadata will be the same.

Also note, the IIS endpoint is completely schema agnostic, meaning it makes no attempt to validate the messages it receives or sends, regardless of what Schemas or Orchestration Port you 'publish'.